# Sheet Specific Scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm currently using the below script to timestamp when an edit is made to column 7 on a sheet named "Sheet 1".

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if ([7].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
   e.range.offset(0, 7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy at HH:mm");
   }  
}
```

I have a second sheet "Sheet 2" which I need to run the same script on but against column 5.

```
function onEdit(e) {
   if ([5].indexOf(e.range.columnStart) != -1) {
   e.range.offset(0, 7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy at HH:mm");
   }  
}
```

I've tried `.getSheetByName("Sheet1")` but just cant seem to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following piece of code.

### Code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var col = e.range.columnStart;
  if(col === 7 || col === 5) {
    var name = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
    if((name === 'Sheet1' && col === 7) || (name === 'Sheet2' && col === 5)) {
      e.range.offset(0, 7).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd.MM.yyyy at HH:mm");
    }
  }
}
```

### Explained

The code reads as follows:

- First check whether we're in column 5 or 7.
- If true, only then retrieve the sheet name
- If the sheet name and the column match, then execute the command

I think *onEdit* functions deserve some extra attention to avoid un-necessary calculations. If you were to include the sheet name, if would check the sheet name every time you change a cell. By restricting that to the columns only, you avoid that.